# How to overwrite html element from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have HTML page with some HTML element with `ID="logo"`. I need to create JS script (with no external libs calls) that will overwrite that html element with other HTML element like `"<div id=logo> stuff inside </div>"`.

Comment: i'm sorry - 'no external libs calls' means ? you don't want to reference code on another site? or have you ruled out using the obvious solution to this - jQuery- included and loaded from your own server?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most of the time, it's just the content you want to replace, not the element itself. If you actually replace the element, you'll find that event handlers attached to it are no longer attached (because they were attached to the old one).

### Replacing its *content*

Replacing the element's *content* is easy:

```
var element;
element = document.getElementById("logo");
if (element) {
    element.innerHTML = "-new content-";
}
```

The `innerHTML` property has only recently been [standardized](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#htmlelement), but is supported by all major browsers (probably most minor ones, too). (See notes below about `innerHTML` and alternatives.)

### Replacing the element iself

Actually *replacing* the element itself is a little harder, but not much:

```
var element, newElement, parent;

// Get the original element
element = document.getElementById("logo");

// Assuming it exists...
if (element) {
    // Get its parent
    parent = element.parentNode;

    // Create the new element
    newElement = document.createElement('div');

    // Set its ID and content
    newElement.id = "logo";
    newElement.innerHTML = "-new content here-";

    // Insert the new one in front of the old one (this temporarily
    // creates an invalid DOM tree [two elements with the same ID],
    // but that's harmless because we're about to fix that).
    parent.insertBefore(newElement, element);

    // Remove the original
    parent.removeChild(element);
}
```

### Notes on `innerHTML` and other DOM manipulation techiques

There are a number of wrinkles around using `innerHTML` in certain browsers, mostly around tables and forms. If you can possibly use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), etc., I'd do so, as they've got workarounds for those issues built-in.

Alternatively, you can use the various other [DOM methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) rather than `innerHTML` (the same ones I used for creating the div and adding/removing, above). Note that in most browsers, doing any significant amount of markup by doing a bunch of `createElement`, `appendChild`, etc., calls rather than using `innerHTML` will be *dramatically* slower. Parsing HTML into their internal structures and displaying it is fundamentally *what browsers do*, and so they're highly optimized to do that. When you go through the DOM interface, you're going through a layer built on top of their internal structures and not getting the advantage of their optimizations. Sometimes you have to do it that way, but mostly, `innerHTML` is your friend.

Comment: I realized my mistake a second after posting...so deleted it...but you beat me to downvoting it...how unfortunate...good answer though. Never thought of doing this myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Muhammad: You're assuming I was the one downvoting; just because i commented it doesn't mean I downvoted. Normally, I'd comment, then downvote several minutes later if the answer hadn't been corrected or removed. But it happens you're right on this occasion -- for some reason I downvoted right away. I don't know why (and can't undo it now, as the answer's been deleted).

Comment: I strongly encourage you to 'actually replace the element itself'. Using `innerHTML` is convenient sometimes, but can also be a vulnerability other times. So if this is your first DOM-adventure, I encourage you to do it the long way at least this once.

Comment: Also take note that in IE6, there are certain elements that cannot be modified with innerHTML, most notably tables.

Comment: @WishCow: I did note that in my answer (*"There are a number of wrinkles..."*)

Comment: @Richard: I see what you're saying, but replacing the element or not and using `innerHTML` or not are separate, unrelated issues. You can reuse the element without using `innerHTML`, just modify its set of child nodes (e.g., adding/removing as necessary); and of course you can replace it by using `innerHTML` (on the parent). The big reasons for not replacing it if you can avoid it are 1) It's more work, and 2) It invalidates all references to the old element, including the ones that associate it with its event ahndlers -- the new element will start out with no handlers attached at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to 'replace' the element or can you just toggle its visibility? This is a technique that's much simpler and will be more efficient. **Most importantly it keeps the content (html) separated from the behavior (javascript).**

```
function toggle() {
    document.getElementById("logo").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("element_to_show").style.display="block";
}
```

see [T.J.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487290/how-to-overwrite-html-element-from-javascript/2487322#2487322) if you actually want to replace the element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to 'replace' the element or can you just toggle its visibility? This is a technique that's much simpler and will be more efficient. Most importantly it keeps the content (html) separated from the behavior (javascript).

Comment: This is rather a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31131802)