# addEventListener object of arrays loop problem

Tags: javascript, dom

I need some help for vanilla JS. I have to buttons one of them show the lesson list other one show exam list. But when I am trying to loop through on their own arrays of object. They overwrite each other. But I want to show lesson list on clicking lesson button and and exam list on clicking exam button. Here is the code. Live Version https://codepen.io/ruslancik/pen/MWyYBzq?editors=1010

JavaScript. I added {once:true} as a last parameter to addEventListener. Otherwise it loop on every Click and added after each other

```js
const exams = [{
    point: '681 points',
    group: 'II group',
    time: '48 minute',
    date: '22 july 2020, 17:30'
  },
  {
    point: '651 points',
    group: 'II group',
    time: '48 minute',
    date: '22 july 2020, 17:30'
  }
];
const lessons = [{
    points: '58%',
    group: 'Math',
    time: '48 minutes',
    date: '22 may 2020, 17:30'
  },
  {
    points: '75%',
    group: 'English',
    time: '36 minute',
    date: '16 may 2020, 17:30'
  }
];

const examSelector = document.getElementById('exam');
const lessonSelector = document.getElementById('lesson');

examSelector.innerText = `Exams (${exams.length})`;
lessonSelector.innerText = `Lessons (${lessons.length})`;


const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');

examSelector.addEventListener('click', function() {
  exams.forEach(item => {
    const resultList = document.createElement('DIV');
    resultList.className = 'result-list'
    resultContainer.appendChild(resultList);
    resultList.innerHTML = `
            <ul>
             <li>${item.points}</li>
             <li>${item.group}</li>
             <li>${item.time}</li>
             <li>${item.date}</li>
            </ul>
            `
  })
}, {
  once: true
});


lessonSelector.addEventListener('click', function() {
  lessons.forEach(item => {
    const resultList = document.createElement('DIV');
    resultList.className = 'result-list'
    resultContainer.appendChild(resultList);
    resultList.innerHTML = `
              <ul>
             <li>${item.points}</li>
             <li>${item.group}</li>
             <li>${item.time}</li>
             <li>${item.date}</li>
            </ul>
            `

  })

}, {
  once: true
});
```

```html
<button id="exam" class="selector">Exam</button>
<button id="lesson" class="selector">Lesson</button>


<div id='result' class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Your logic is only ever appending children to the container.  So I'm not sure how this would be removing previous things appending to the results.

Comment: In fact your codepen is not removing things.  So, what's the problem again?

Comment: I want to see exams only when I am clicking exam button and lessons only when I am clicking lesson button. Not both on the same time

Comment: `resultContainer.innerHTML = '';` at the top of your event handlers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite html element from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487290/how-to-overwrite-html-element-from-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey       when I am doing resultContainer.innerHTML = ''; it show just the  the last item from list. I will check the link

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, this link did not help. Thanks anyway

Comment: "at the top of your event handlers", not within the `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Dave solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to do it like this?

```js
//Neticeler

const exams = [
    {
        points: '681 points',
        group: 'II group',
        time: '48 minute',
        date: '22 july 2020, 17:30'
    },
    {
       points: '651 points',
        group: 'II group',
        time: '48 minute',
        date: '22 july 2020, 17:30'
    }
];
const lessons = [
    {
        points: '58%',
        group: 'Math',
        time: '48 minutes',
        date: '22 may 2020, 17:30'
    },
    {
        points: '75%',
        group: 'English',
        time: '36 dəqiqə',
        date: '16 may 2020, 17:30'
    }
];

const examSelector = document.getElementById('exam');
const lessonSelector = document.getElementById('lesson');

examSelector.innerText = `Exams (${exams.length})`;
lessonSelector.innerText = `Lessons (${lessons.length})`;


const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');

examSelector.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const resultList = document.querySelector('.result-list') || document.createElement('DIV');
    resultList.innerHTML = '';
    exams.forEach(item => {
        if (resultList.parentNode) resultList.parentNode.removeChild(resultList);
        resultList.className = 'result-list'
        resultContainer.appendChild(resultList);
        resultList.innerHTML += `
        <ul>
         <li>${item.points}</li>
         <li>${item.group}</li>
         <li>${item.time}</li>
         <li>${item.date}</li>
        </ul>
        `
     })
});


lessonSelector.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const resultList = document.querySelector('.result-list') || document.createElement('DIV');
    resultList.innerHTML = '';
    lessons.forEach(item => {
        
        if (resultList.parentNode) resultList.parentNode.removeChild(resultList);
        resultList.className = 'result-list'
        resultContainer.appendChild(resultList);
        resultList.innerHTML += `
          <ul>
         <li>${item.points}</li>
         <li>${item.group}</li>
         <li>${item.time}</li>
         <li>${item.date}</li>
        </ul>
        `

     })

});
```

```html
<button id="exam" class="selector">Exam</button>
<button id="lesson" class="selector">Lesson</button>


<div id='result' class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But now it just show one list item(last one) not both two.

Comment: ah sorry didn't notice that, check now

Comment: Thank you Dave. You made my day :)